# google maps upload photos as markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am trying to make a custom page that would look like this

[image]

if i have a page where you can upload an image and enter description which feeds into a sql dB using PHP, how could one create a map of image thumbnails instead of markers?
 this photo was taken from: http://www.blocsoft.com/bmap/ but after browsing thru their site i didnt see anything about image thumbnails as markers

Comment: just found this link, should do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526304/php-extract-gps-exif-data

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, but less flexible, approach would be to store the photographs in Panoramio and enable the maps Panoramio layer http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#PanoramioLibrary

Comment: because of this project, i cant use panoramio.  i would need to store the data local

Comment: Fair enough - the sample you provided looks as if it was implemented via Panoramio.  @Michael suggestion will work for you but the images will need to be accessible on a web server.

Comment: actually i think that this method is the only way.  the marker method will not work for so many images.  should look into panoramio's api

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to do this via Javascript.

See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#SimpleIcons
Example @ http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple.html

Basically, you can use PHP to populate the markers within the javascript markup, then let JS init it.

Comment: the complex example is more of what i would need http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex.html

Comment: Complex would most likely do exactly what you want.  It is a bit of code for a simple marker, but that's what google requires to work with their API.