# Mapping exif data to long/lat

Tags: php, geolocation, gps, exif, geotagging

I'm using the php `exif_read_data` function to get the long and lat, then I'm converting them into a format the google can use, however they always seem to be a few miles out.  The same country, just not the right position (iPhoto will give me the correct position, however).  The code is as follows

```
public function get_location() {
    global $the_image;

    if(!empty($the_image)) {
      $exif = $this->get_exif();

      $degLong = $exif['GPSLongitude'][0];
      $minLong = $exif['GPSLongitude'][1];
      $secLong = $exif['GPSLongitude'][2];
      $refLong = $exif['GPSLongitudeRef'];

      $degLat = $exif['GPSLatitude'][0];
      $minLat = $exif['GPSLatitude'][1];
      $secLat = $exif['GPSLatitude'][2];
      $refLat = $exif['GPSLatitudeRef'];

      $long = $this->to_decimal($degLong, $minLong, $secLong, $refLong);
      $lat  = $this->to_decimal($degLat, $minLat, $secLat, $refLat);
      echo $long . "<br />" . $lat . "<br/>";

    } else {
      echo "Supply an image";
    }
}

  function to_decimal($deg, $min, $sec, $hem){
    $d = $deg + ((($min/60) + ($sec/3600))/100);
    return ($hem =='S' || $hem=='W') ?  $d*=-1 : $d;
  }
```

Can anyone see what would make it return the wrong data, is my `to_decimal` function wrong?

Comment: Which package are you using? Can you please show how you extracted gps information in PHP?

Comment: Hi @ultrasamad this is a really old question and shouldn't really be resurrected but I was using the PHP `exif_read_data` method found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php. No packages, just PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You devide the minutes and seconds by 100, but well, you shouldn't:

```
$d = $deg + ((($min/60) + ($sec/3600))/100);
```

should be:

```
$d = $deg + (($min/60) + ($sec/3600));
```

[one minute is 1/60 degree and a second is 1/60 minute.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion)

---

for a more thorough answer, see here: [PHP extract GPS EXIF data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526304/php-extract-gps-exif-data)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that.  I don't even know why I added that.  Thank you, it is 3:40AM here - that might be why :)

Comment: 4:40 here, but yes, another pair of eyes makes all the difference sometimes :)

Comment: This code is still not correct. Locations are still a few hundred miles out. Check out this example here by Gerald Kaszuba that works accurately:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526304/php-extract-gps-exif-data

Comment: Thanks, I'll include the link in my answer so it can be found more easily, since this problem was rather a slip of the pen.