# PHP extracting EXIF GPS data

Tags: php, gps, exif

With this EXIF GPS data:

```
    ["GPSLatitudeRef"]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["GPSLatitude"]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "65539/0"
        [1]=>
        string(17) "-1542717440/65539"
        [2]=>
        string(8) "196608/0"
    }
    ["GPSLongitudeRef"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["GPSLongitude"]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(20) "39321600/-1166016512"
        [1]=>
        string(21) "1111490956/1811939343"
        [2]=>
        string(22) "1111491292/-1725956081"
    }
```

Using the above code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526304/php-extract-gps-exif-data) (thanks [Gerald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11125/gerald-kaszuba)) I get these Latitude & Longitude values:

```
-392.31537456069,-0.023678137550796
```

This is not correct.  It's doing my head in as the code works, but the answer is wrong in this case!  Many other images work fine, there just seems to be some logic missing to cater for something in this dat.  For example, when I load the image in to iPhoto (sorry for the Apple example to those without Macs) it gets the answer right; this EXIF data is for a picture near the Red Sea.

I'm now wondering if there is a division by zero issue...

Is there something in the fact that the second half of `GPSLatitude[0]` is 0? Maybe this creates a division by zero problem in Gerald's code?