# How to convert GPS exif to geography?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, exif, geography

I have attachments table which has `GPSLatitude` and `GPSLongitude` columns for each attachment. It's legacy code which is populating the fields and the values looks like:

```
GPSLatitude
50/1,5/1,1897/100

GPSLongitude
14/1,25/1,4221/100
```

Is there any build in function which I can use in order to convert them to latitude and longitude decimal values like this:

```
Location Latitude   
41.5803 
Location Longitude
-83.9124
```

I can implement SQL CLR function if this can be done easier with `.net` also.

What is most difficult for me right now is to understand what these values represent. The legacy code is using some API with no documentation about the returned format and how to read it.

---

The values above are just for showing how the data is formatted. The following library is used to get the values - [chestysoft](http://www.chestysoft.com/imagefile/exifreadcf.htm) like this:

```
 IF Image.ExifValueByName("GPSLatitude") <> "" THEN GPSLatitude = Image.ExifValueByName("GPSLatitude") ELSE GPSLatitude = NULL END IF
 IF Image.ExifValueByName("GPSLongitude") <> "" THEN GPSLongitude = Image.ExifValueByName("GPSLongitude") ELSE GPSLongitude = NULL END IF
```

Comment: Could those legacy values be some convoluted variant of "Degrees, Minutes and Seconds" format?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze I guess so. I am searching and it must be `(1) degrees, (2) degrees and decimal minutes, or (3) degrees, minutes, and decimal seconds.` -  I guess the `,` is separating these values.

Comment: In your data is the value after the first two `/` always 1 and after the third `/` always 100?

Comment: Is `50/1,5/1,1897/100` equal to `41.5803 ` or are the values in the question just there to show the formatting?

Comment: If you menage to convert those values to more commonly used latitude/longitude values, do you have a way to validate those values?

Comment: @MJH Just formatting. I have no idea to what this could be translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you should read it as:

```
50/1: 50 Degrees
5/1: 5 Minutes
1897/100: 18.97 Seconds
```

This would put the location you've given in New York (assuming N/W), does that make sense? If you have no way to validate the output it's very difficult to make any other suggestion... See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526304/php-extract-gps-exif-data?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

In the link you provided, you can upload a picture to view the exif data. There you can test with known locations. It is also apparent that in the values you mentioned, the `GPSLatitudeRef` and `GPSLongitudeRef` are missing. You need these to change the values to a location. Do you have those values in your table? Otherwise you'll have to make (wild) assumptions.

This is by the way the [standard](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/GPS.html) EXIF notation for latitude/longitude; I assume there are many, many tools to convert it.

Comment: Those are the assumptions I have used in my answer.

Comment: @MJH, not really. What I meant was, the `/` in the value should be read as a division. So you shouldn't divide by `60.0` and `360000.0`, but by `1` and `100` respectively.

Comment: I have divided minutes by 60 and seconds by 3600 to convert them to degrees, the intention is to add the three values together to give an answer in degrees.

Comment: @MJH, Ah yes, I was still thinking in minutes/seconds rather than degrees. I think you would still need to divide the seconds by 100 though (and the minutes by 1(there might be a different value to divide by in other values)).

Comment: That's something for the OP to watch out for.  :)

Comment: It seems that you are right. These values recorded as float using division. I have tested this creating a attachment, uploading it and then locating the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that @Cool_Br33ze is correct, and the data is in degrees, minutes and seconds, you can calculate the values you need using the following:

```
declare @v varchar(30) = '50/1,5/1,1897/100'

select  @v Original_Value,
        convert(decimal(18,4), left(@v, charindex('/', @v) - 1)) [Degrees],
        convert(decimal(18,4), substring(
                                            @v, 
                                            charindex(',', @v) + 1, 
                                            charindex('/', @v, charindex(',', @v)) - (charindex(',', @v) + 1)
                                        ) / 60.0
        ) [Minutes],
        convert(decimal(18,4), substring(
                                            @v, 
                                            charindex(',', @v, (charindex(',', @v) + 1)) + 1, 
                                            charindex('/', @v, charindex(',', @v, (charindex(',', @v) + 1))) - (charindex(',', @v, (charindex(',', @v) + 1)) + 1)
                                        ) / 360000.0
        ) [Seconds]
```

It looks a bit of a mess, but it splits out the degrees, minutes and seconds (converted to `DECIMAL(18,4)`), all you need to do is add the three values together to get your Lat/Long value in degrees.

I'd test it thoroughly before implementing it though.